# Rails RESTfull API Documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api, documentation, yard

im searching for a Documentation Framework that supports the following features:

- Generated from Code Comments
- Searchable
- Styling customizable
- NTH: Linked references (If i reference a class somewhere class name should be linked to class documentation)

I want to use it to document an RESTfull API i'm working on

I know about YARDoc, but would be nice to gather some alternatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matt Silverman created a pretty comprehensive lists of what is available out there now for gen'ing docs from code.

http://www.mattsilverman.com/2013/02/tools-to-generate-beautiful-api-documentation.html

Comment: Thanks that's really quite useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from YARD, you can generate RDOC project documentation using the following rake task:

```
rake doc:app
```

After this, your docs will be located in the `doc/app` folder and can be viewed by opening the `index.html` file in your browser. It will include the (currently probably generic) `doc/README_FOR_APP` file.

Hope this helps :)